# Unable to append to list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

```py
    if sample_collected == 'true':
            b_id = list(Booking.objects.filter(center__isnull=False,org_type='homedx').values_list('id', flat=True))
            for booki_id in b_id:
                print("Booking ID", booki_id)
                if booki_id in list(ReceivedPackageTubes.objects.values_list('booking_id', flat=True)):

                    packages = list(Booking.objects.filter(id=booki_id).values_list('packages__name', flat=True))
                    print("Packages", packages)
                    count_tube = []
                    for i in packages:
                        pt = package_models.PackageTubes.objects.filter(package__name=i).values_list('tubequantity__tube__name', flat=True).count()
                        count_tube.append(pt)

                    total_tubes = sum(count_tube)
                    print("Total Tubes", total_tubes)

                    collected = list(ReceivedPackageTubes.objects.filter(booking_id=booki_id).values_list('booking_id', flat=True))
                    print("Collected", collected)
                    collected_ids = []
                    
                    if len(collected) == total_tubes:
                        collected_ids.append(booki_id)
                    print("Collected ID", collected_ids)
```

In the last line if `len(collected) == total_tubes`. I am trying to append `**collected_id**`. in `collected_ids = []`. Every time it is appending one. I know I need to use for loop but I am unable to do that. Can somebody help. I am learning Python and Django. Thank you !!

Comment: "it is appending one." What is there to append in group? If there is a list of items to append, then you can use `list.extend`

Answer (score 1):

You're using a for loop to iterate over `booki_id` elements in `b_id`, and adding them to the `collected_ids` list. However, each time you process the next `booki_id`, you're resetting `collected_ids` to an empty list. Try moving the line:
`collected_ids = []`
outside the for loop, so that you only initialize the list once and avoid overwriting it.